# Backbone collection and model structure

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I have an app in backbone that has essentially 3 main components: groups, users, and posts. I have models and collections for all 3, and then on top of that I am tracking in depth analytics for each type. Multiple users belong to a single group by the way.

For example, I have another collection called groups_index that has the fields: date, average # of posts, and average post length ( with a new row for each date ).  And then I also have a user_index collection that has the fields: date, group_id, average # of posts, and average post length.

I want to be able to generate charts that show the average number of posts for a group across time and the same for the users of a specific group.

Does it make more sense to combine everything into the groups_index collection and add an user_id field? Or would that over-complicate it when showing the group average charts?

Comment: It's a little hard to judge how complicated something is without seeing the code. Can you post a jsfiddle or some sample code?

Comment: And how large are your collections?

Comment: I haven't written out any of the code because I wanted to make sure I had the best structure first. There are about 200 groups. Groups usually have between 100 - 10,000 posts and between 1 - 100 users. So for the group_index data there would be 365 rows for every group each year then the user_index would have 365 rows for every user in a group each year.